# URL was not found in the server

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to deploy my ml model in flask. The error appear when i am trying access my height-weight.html page from the home.html page.

code for app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This works perfectly fine. It render home.html. No problem here.

Output 1:-

[image: image1]

But as soon as I click Check Project button following error occurs.

Output 2:-

[image: image2]

Code for height-weight.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle


app = Flask(__name__)

model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/predict')
def weight_predict():
    return render_template('height-weight.html')


@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        height = float(request.form['height'])
        gender = float(request.form['gender'])

        prediction = model.predict([[gender, height]])

        output = round(prediction[0], 2)

    return render_template('height-weight.html', weights = output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And finally my html code for height-weight.html look like this.

Code:-

```
<section id='form'>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Height Weight Prediction</h1>

                    <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="get">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <label>Gender</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id='gender' placeholder="Input Your Gender" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <label>Height</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id='height' placeholder="Input Your Height" required="required">
                                <small class="form-text text-muted">Please input your height in 'Inch'.</small>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit">Predict Weight</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    {{ weights }}
                </div>
            </section>
```

My expected output is to show height-weight.html pages from where i can predict the weight. This is my error. Hope you guys understand my error and please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting the page to `127.0.0.1:5000/height-weight.html` which is looking for the HTML file on the backend server. You need to redirect the page to /redirect by providing it in an anchor tag.

Flask renders the HTML page and returns the response it doesn't serve the HTML page directly. That's why you are getting 404 error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: as you suggest i used the anchor tag but still the same error.  <a href="templates/height-weight.html">Check Project</a>

Comment: `href` value should be the URI PATH to the predict view. As of now you have allowed only POST method. Change the /predict to something else and allow get method also.

Comment: i have done everything that you suggest but i am having some new error. This is my git link https://github.com/PashupatiPariyar/Multi-Model-Web-App . I would be thankfull if you help me by making changes. Thank you so much.

Comment: I saw the files and issue is that you have created two flask Apps in two different files. Just put all of the functions into one file or use same Flask object to create views.

Comment: Bro still same error. Now i need serious problem. Please help me man. https://github.com/PashupatiPariyar/Multi-Model-Web-App.git please edit it. And thank you for everything. God bless you man.